# how to set jsonp callback in retrieving restful web service data via jquery

Tags: json, rest, jquery, jsonp

I have asked a question regarding invalid label on firebug which happens when I try to retrieve data from my restful web service. Most of the answers I received was about setting a callback function. but I can't seem to get the right juice from it. can you show me an exact code on how to do it? or atleast correct the code here:

```
        type: "GET",
        cache: false, 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        processdata:true,
        jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "success",
        url: 'http://localhost:8732/Service1/data/10',

        success : function success(data) {
            jsonResponse = eval("(" + data + ")");
            alert(jsonResponse)
        },
        error : function(req,status, ex) {

            alert(ex);
        }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, you've got a lot of unnecessary stuff there. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8732/Service1/data/10',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    error: function(req, status, ex) {
        // your code here
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //your code here
        // Please note: you don't need to 'eval' the json response.
        // The 'data' variable will be loaded with the object that the json string represents.
        // By the way, don't use 'eval', ever.
    }
});
```

jQuery will take care of the callback on the url. See here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

**UPDATE**
Why jsonp? If you're getting this from localhost, why not just json? As discussed in the comments below, your server currently is not capable of a jsonp response, but it can do json.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but i still have the same result. invalid label {"Id":10,"Name":"Leo Messi"} on firebug. any ideas?

Comment: You're not `eval`ing in the `success` function are you? Please show some revised code.

Comment: This is the code i used. i've read about eval thing. and yes i'm not eval-ing in the success.     $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8732/Service1/data/10',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    error: function(req, status, ex) {
     alert("hi");
    },
    success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
    }
   });

Comment: `data` is not a string. It's an object. Is that what `console.log()` is choking on? UPDATE: No it's not, since the function accepts objects. Can you supply more info?

Comment: i think so. sorry i'm really new to json. i'm in the process of learning it. i just want to somehow show the data either by alert or by console. can you give me an insight about this one? thank you for your fast response. UPDATE: i think that's it. the error is invalid label and it has a small arrow pointing to " of {"Id":10,"Name":"Leo Messi"} in the middle of { and Id. hope that helps.

Comment: If you want to see the json as it is given from the server, just go to `http:/localhost:8732/Service1/data/10?callback=myFunction`. You'll see the exact string given in response to the ajax call. Please paste it here.

Comment: yes. it worked. but i'm still puzzled why does it says invalid label and it always alerts "hi" meaning it has encountered an error.

Comment: Please paste the result of pointing your browser to: `http:/localhost:8732/Service1/data/10?callback=myFunction`

Comment: actually even with this one it will work. http:/localhost:8732/Service1/data/10 and the result is {"Id":10,"Name":"Leo Messi"} 
Wait, the myFunction you are referring would be on the server side?

Comment: Try it exactly as I had it: `http:/localhost:8732/Service1/data/10?callback=myFunction`.

Comment: same result. {"Id":10,"Name":"Leo Messi"}

Comment: That's the problem, then. You don't have a jsonp service. The response should have been `myFunction({"Id":10,"Name":"Leo Messi"});`. JSONP services wrap the json in a function call. The name of the function is whatever was supplied in the `callback=` part of the URL.

Comment: oh. so meaning the restful web service is causing the problem? do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: yes. locally. i created it out. i just copied the solution file. http://stevenhollidge.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-create-json-wcf-restful-service.html

Comment: OK. You'll need to reprogram it to take the value of `callback` from the url, and change the response to use that function name in the answer. For example, if the url parameter is `callback=FrED` then your response should be `FrED({"Id":10,"Name":"Leo Messi"});`. If no `callback` is specified, then the response you're giving now will work. But I guess this begs the question: Why jsonp? Are you planning to request this cross-domain?

Comment: Please check the revised version of my last post. Why jsonp?

Comment: but it doesn't return anything. i mean it still alerts hi. and failed to get or abort on the process.

Comment: I don't understand. What doesn't return anything? Show some code, please.

Comment: $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8732/Service1/data/10',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(req, status, ex) {
     alert("hi");
    },
    success: function getData(data) {
     console.log(data);
    }
   }); i changed it to json. yet GET http://localhost:8732/Service1/data/10 200 OK
  78ms is the error.

Comment: The format for the json call is different. See this page. Use either `$.getJSON()` or `$.ajax()` using the format in the first box on this page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: what would be the difference? by the looks of it it is still the same. can you give me a sample code? thank you.